# CoreData Fetch Request casting [Any] to [AnyObject] produces memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-leaks, swift3

I am facing a memory leak which am unable to understand
PFB

[image]

Call trace:

1. +0x196  callq               "DYLD-STUB$$NSManagedObjectContext.fetch (NSFetchRequest) throws -> [A]"
2. +0x8c   callq               "_arrayForceCast ([A]) -> [B]"
3. +0xde   callq               "Collection.map ((A.Iterator.Element) throws -> A1) throws -> [A1]"
4. +0x19e  callq               "ContiguousArray.reserveCapacity(Int) -> ()"
5. +0xaa   callq               "_ContiguousArrayBuffer.init(uninitializedCount : Int, minimumCapacity : Int) -> _ContiguousArrayBuffer"
6. +0x42   callq               "ManagedBufferPointer.init(_uncheckedBufferClass : AnyObject.Type, minimumCapacity : Int) -> ManagedBufferPointer"
7. +0x0f   callq               "swift_slowAlloc"
8. +0x04   callq               "DYLD-STUB$$malloc"
9. +0x13   callq               "malloc_zone_malloc"
10. +0x8f  movzbl              71543(%rip), %eax

[image]

[image]

Edit:

I Further investigated the code and i found out that the real leak is when i try to force cast type [Any] to [AnyObject] in coredata fetch request

```
func fetchEntity<T: NSManagedObject>(entityClass:T.Type,setPredicate:NSPredicate?) -> [AnyObject]
{
    let entityName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = setPredicate
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var result:[AnyObject] = []
    do
    {
        result = try cdh.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) --> right here is the leak, when i cast the return object of [Any] to [AnyObject]

    }catch let error as NSError
    {
        debugPrint("error in fetchrequest is",error)
        result = []
    }

    return result
}
```

EDIT:
@Jon,Kuba

```
Model.getEntities(entityType: EX_TEACHER.self, completion: {[unowned self] entityobjects in
            self.teacherList = entityobjects
    })
```

// in model class

```
 class func getEntities<T: NSManagedObject>(entityType: T.Type,completion: ([AnyObject]) -> Void)
{
    let  teacherList = coreDataOperation.fetchEntity(entityClass: entityType, setPredicate: nil)

    completion(teacherList)

}
```

// cdh.managedObjectContext code

```
lazy var cdh:CoreDataStore = {
    let cdh = CoreDataStore()
    return cdh
}()

class CoreDataStore: NSObject{
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}() }
```

Comment: Please paste a code when u're calling this fetchEntity func. You're performing selector? Taking unretainedValue?

Comment: Which context are you using for fetching? what is just created for this fetch?

Comment: edited with requested code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of compilation and google search. i gave up and downloaded a new xcode version 8.3. (previous was 8.1)

Then i retested the project and guess what.....?
no leaks anymore. Well we can guess that it was xcode 8.1 version issues.

EDIT:

**Debugging**

**Resolved Issues
The Memory Debugger for macOS and the iOS Simulator fixes reporting of false memory leaks for Swift classes containing either fields of type enum, or classes that inherit from certain Objective-C framework classes. (27932061)
False reporting can still occur for iOS, watchOS, and tvOS applications. See (29335813) in Known Issues, below.**

**Known Issues
The Memory Debugger for iOS, watchOS, and tvOS applications can report false memory leaks when debugging Swift classes containing either fields of type enum, or classes that inherit from certain Objective-C framework classes. (29335813)**

[apple Xcode 8.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)

Comment: Did you try in 8.2 ? Was there any memory issues ?

Comment: Kudos for digging through that and sticking to figuring this out. I had a hunch the old version reported some stuff wrong (and read several people mentioning that, too), but this confirms it. One thing less I need to worry about myself, helped me out!

Comment: Thanks.. Glad that helped you out. Am sure more people are facing this issue. i hope they find some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
        do
        {

        var result: AnyObject = try cdh.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) 
       let resultMirror = Mirror(reflecting: result) 
       print(resultMirror.subjectType)    //gives you the return type  from coredata


        }catch let error as NSError
        {
            debugPrint("error in fetchrequest is",error)
            result = []
        }
```

Comment: My question was about memory leak not return type, this answer is unrelated, anyway this is the mirror type output-> Array<AnyObject>